# SatisfyImportsOnce vs ComposeParts

Tags: c#, mef

Can someone please explain the difference between `SatisfyImportsOnce` and `ComposeParts` and why one would work where the other doesn't?

Specifically I have a MVC Web application that I am using MEF in. Below is some code (from that application) that works when I use `SatisfyImportsOnce` but doesn't when I use `ComposeParts`. My understanding is that `ComposeParts` creates composable parts from an array of attributed objects and composes them in the specified composition container and that `SatisfyImportsOnce`  composes the specified part by using the specified composition service. To my simple monkey brain even though the English is different they are semantically the same. Both use the `CompositionContainer` to spit exported types at import targets.

```
public class FormPartCustomatorFactory
{

    [ImportMany(typeof(ICustomRenderer), AllowRecomposition = true)]
    private readonly List<Lazy<ICustomRenderer, ICustomRendererMetaData>> _rendererImports = new List<Lazy<ICustomRenderer, ICustomRendererMetaData>>();

    private readonly Dictionary<string, Lazy<ICustomRenderer, ICustomRendererMetaData>> _renderers;

    public static readonly FormPartCustomatorFactory Instance = new FormPartCustomatorFactory();

    static CompositionContainer _container;

    private FormPartCustomatorFactory()
    {
        using (var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, "*.dll"))
        {               
            _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            _container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this); // <- Works
            // _container.ComposeParts(this); // DOESN'T Work
            _renderers = _rendererImports.ToDictionary(q => q.Metadata.Name, q => q);
        }
    }

    ~FormPartCustomatorFactory()
    {
        _container.Dispose();
    }

    public static ICustomRenderer Find(string name)
    {
        return Instance._renderers[name].Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`SatisyImportsOnce` will compose a type without registering it for recomposition. So, if you intend to use a type without support for recomposition, you can use `SatisfyImportsOnce` and it will do the work as usual, but any changes in the container (new parts added, or parts removed), then your instance won't automatically be recomposed to offer up these new parts.

In your instance, you are using:

```
[ImportMany(typeof(ICustomRenderer), AllowRecomposition = true)]
```

...but through `SatisfyImportsOnce`, this import won't be recomposed.

If you are not worried about recomposition, you could change your code use constructor injection, so you could do:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public FormPartCustomatorFactory(IEnumerable<Lazy<ICustomRenderer, ICustomRendererMetadata>> renderers)
{
    if (renderers == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("renderers");

    _renderers = renderers.ToDictionary(r => r.Metadata.Name, r => r);
}
```

The reason I would suggest constructor injection, is that the set of `Lazy<ICustomRenderer, ICustomRendererMetadata>` instances are an explicit dependency your type requires, so it would be better to instantiate your type in a usable state, rather than instantiate and then require an additional step to get it ready for first time use.

This makes your `FormPartCustomatorFactory` type much more testable. To this end, if you were to change the constructor as such, then your method of making it a singleton wouldn't work. Instead, you could take advantage of the lifetime management functionality of MEF, so possibly redesign your type as:

```
public interface IFormPartCustomatorFactory
{
    ICustomRenderer Find(string name);
}

[Export(typeof(IFormPartCustomerFactory)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class FormPartCustomatorFactory : IFormPartCustomatorFactory
{
    private IEnumerable<Lazy<ICustomRenderer, ICustomRendereMetadata>> _renderers;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public FormPartCustomatorFactory(IEnumerable<Lazy<ICustomRenderer, ICustomRendererMetadata>> renderers)
    {
        if (renderers == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("renderers");

        _renderers = renderers;
    }

    public ICustomRenderer Find(string name)
    {
        return _renderers
            .Where(r => r.Metadata.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            .Select(r => r.Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Doing it this way means that your type is not dependent on MEF, it can be used without it, its more testable, and the `CompositionContainer` will manage the lifetime of the part, in this case the `CreationPolicy.Shared` (which is the default for exported types), uses a singleton lifetime strategy. You can then import an instance of `IFormPartCustomator`, you import the same singleton instance.

I would also argue that calling it a `Factory` is possibly wrong, as a factory is designed to create new instances, whereas, your type will only create one instance of each `ICustomRenderer`. If this is the intended behaviour, maybe it would be better called an `FormPartCustomatorService`, that implements an `IFormPartCusomatorService` interface? If you want to spin up new instances each time, you could look at `ExportFactory<ICustomRenderer, ICustomRendererMetadata>`.

Answer (score 13):

As Matthew mentions, `SatisfyImportsOnce` doesn't register the part for recomposition.  This means the MEF container doesn't hold a reference to the part.

In addition, `SatisfyImportsOnce` only satisfies the imports of a part, but ignores any exports it has.  `ComposeParts` would add the exports to the container too.

Comment: "ComposeParts would add the exports to the container too." - this was what I was looking for :)

Comment: ComposeParts seems also to be way more expensive than SatisfyImportOnce + CompositionBatch. I migrate to this solution in our Unity Project as it was responsible for large spikes. Way better now.