# When do I pass the RegistrationBuilder to Catalog?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, mef

With the new fluent MEF programming model, if I have multiple catalogs:

1. To which catalog do I pass my `RegistrationBuilder` to???
2. Do I need to pass `RegistrationBuilder` to `SatisfyImportsOnce` call?
3. Which of `SatisfyImportsOnce` or `ComposeParts` do I use? (has anything changed with this in fluent mef?)

E.g. Here is an example to llustrate my confusion (see comments on the r.h.s):

```
// Get pre-wired registration builder
RegistrationBuilder rb = new MefCompositionRoot().CommonRegistrationBuilder();

// Register this WCF service class
rb.ForType<LogService>().Export<LogService>();


var assembly = typeof (LogService).Assembly;
var assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(assembly, rb); // <-- HERE?
var dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog("bin", rb);   // <-- and HERE?

// Combine catalogs
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(dirCatalog);
catalog.Catalogs.Add(assemblyCatalog);

var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this, rb);//  THIS?
container.ComposeParsts(this); ///or THIS?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can put the `RegistrationBuilder` to any of the catalogs you want to use MEF Conventions with. If you want to use only the Conventions Model, then use it in all catalogs. If the `DirectoryCatalog` in your sample code, will load assemblies containing only Attributed exports/imports then you do not need the `RegistrationBuilder`. Note that both models (Attributed and Contentions) can **coexist**. So, you could add the `RegistrationBuilder` to all catalogs unless there might be a type that satisfies a rule (configured using the RegistrationBuilder) that you do **not** want to use in your `CompositionContainer`.
2. This overload of [SatisfyImportsOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136467.aspx) is a riddle. From the documentation (and from a quick look at MEF's source) it looks like you can use a specific RegistrationBuilder ad-hoc. In reality I have only managed to use it with the code sample that follows.
3. [SatisfyImportsOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd779466.aspx) disables recomposition. Check out this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419319/mef-satisfyimportsonce-vs-composeparts/6422332#6422332) on this subject.

---

Sample using SatisfyImportsOnce(Object, ReflectionContext)

```
private static void TestLateRegistration_SameBuilder_Ok()
{            
    var rb = new RegistrationBuilder();            
    var assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(LogService).Assembly, rb);

    using (var container = new CompositionContainer(assemblyCatalog))
    {                
        rb.ForType<LogService>().Export();
        var server = new TypeImportingLogService();
        //Use the same RegistrationBuilder.
        container.SatisfyImportsOnce(server, rb);
    }
}
```